# Callout (with line) into an image in function of the coordinates of a point

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, callout

We suppose to take, as example, a very good @Jake's solution: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)
where I have put a generic image (I not remember where I have download it).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{cat}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image]

I make my images in pdf using Adobe Illustrator. Is there a package that can generate this kind of callouts with comments that can be placed according to the coordinates of the grid. Probably a grid with squares, than the rectangle grid, could be more useful.

Here there is an example, where the line of the callout is fixed if I can to choose the coordinate of a point `(x,y)`.

[image]

I don't remember where I downloaded the photo right now. Excuse me.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}`? (see my user profile ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have seen your profile but your code (excuse me for this) has any problem. "Are there any missing closing brackets in your document? Use Ctrl+Shift+9 to activate Bracket Matcher tool which will help you to spot the problem." using Papeeria and with TeXworks the process stops.

Comment: On my computer the code from my profile works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I meant is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,shadows.blur,positioning}
\definecolor{dunno}{RGB}{182,192,180}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
    {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \path (0.5,0.5) coordinate (c)
         node[blur shadow,text opacity=1,opacity=0.8,font=\sffamily,
          align=center, fill=dunno,rounded corners,draw=none,rectangle callout,
          anchor=pointer,callout absolute pointer={(c)},above right=1cm and 2cm of c] {This is
          a duck.\\ Are ducks beings?}; 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are callouts always on the right? Is there a possibility of having them on the left too?

Comment: @Sebastiano The callout is right because it says `above right=...`. If you say `above left=...`, it will be left.